# Multikey maps with lower and upper bound iteration for all keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

Let's say I'm using a map that uses three strings as a key.  Here's a quick example struct:

```
struct ExampleMapKey
{
 std::string key0;
 std::string key1;
 std::string key2;

 bool operator<(const ExampleMapKey& other) const
 {
  if (key0 < other.key0) return true;
  else if (key0 > other.key0) return false;

  if (key1 < other.key1) return true;
  else if (key1 > other.key1) return false;

  return key2 < other.key2;
 }
}
```

Now, this works fine until I decide I want to use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.  If I want to find the range of values formed by any key0, any key1 starting with "ab", and any key2 starting with "cd", using those 2 functions with `ExampleMapKey("", "ab", "cd")` and `ExampleMapKey("", "ac", "ce")` respectively will have me iterating through keys that don't fulfill my requirements.  Or will I miss keys that do?  Either way, it's wrong.

It seems what I need is a data structure that explicitly indexes by each key, and will also allow me to perform potentially complicated `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` iterations.  Is there such a thing?  I'm not necessarily using strings, nor am I limited to only 3 keys, so it needs to be STL-style or similarly generic.

Comment: [Boost::MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Boost Multi-index Containers Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) can be of help.

   **Update:** After rereading your question, I think you may have to do what is taught in db classes; you would have to use one of the indices to create a temporary result, and prune that result, based on your second constraint (alternatively, you can run each constraint on each index, joining the results). Boost Multi-index Containers will only allow lookup on one index at a time AFAIK.
2. For the particular type of query that you asked, you might be able to come up with a very specialized data structure that can help, by adding indices on partitions of indices. That is for example, you take the 2nd index, split it in half, rewrite a 3rd index for the first half, and for the 2nd half. Then you split each half and repeat. This way, you can select a section of the 2nd index, and then subsequently select a part of the 3rd index that is within (approximately) that part of the 2nd index. But I don't know of any library that does this.
3. Another approach might be some sort of multi-dimensional data structure, though I am not familiar with using such a structure with non-numeric keys. For example, imagine your keys were integers, you could use a 3D [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or other spatial index, and query for a cubic range. For example: (using [libssrckdtree](http://www.savarese.com/software/libssrckdtree/), seems it might work with strings too):

Codes for (3):

```
#include <ssrc/spatial/kd_tree.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

#include <string>

typedef std::array<std::string, 3> Point;

typedef ssrc::spatial::kd_tree<Point, Point> Tree;

int main()
{
  Tree tree;

  Point point = {{"any1","aa1","cc1"}};
  tree[point] = point;

  point = {{"any2","ab1","cc1"}};
  tree[point] = point;

  point = {{"any3","ab1","cd1"}};
  tree[point] = point;
  point = {{"any4","ab1","cd2"}};
  tree[point] = point;
  point = {{"any5","ab1","cd3"}};
  tree[point] = point;


  point = {{"any22","ac1","cc1"}};
  tree[point] = point;

  point = {{"any33","ac1","cd1"}};
  tree[point] = point;
  point = {{"any44","ac1","cd2"}};
  tree[point] = point;
  point = {{"any55","ac1","cd3"}};
  tree[point] = point;


  point = {{"any6","aa1","cd2"}};
  tree[point] = point;
  point = {{"any7","aa1","cd3"}};
  tree[point] = point;

  Point lower{ { "any0", "ab", "cd" } }, upper{ { "any9", "ac", "cd2" } };

  for(Tree::const_iterator it = tree.begin(lower, upper), end = tree.end();
      it != end; ++it)
  {
    Point point = it->first;
    Point value = it->second;
    std::cout << point[0] << ", " << point[1] << ", " << point[2] << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
any3, ab1, cd1
any4, ab1, cd2
```

Answer (score 0):

In such `std::map` there wouldn't be a single range, it would be set of ranges.

Consider such keys (sorted as defined by your comparator object):

```
#0 {"aa", "aa", "cb" },
#1 {"aa", "ab", "cd" },
#2 {"aa", "abb", "cdd" },
#3 {"ab", "aa", "cb" },
#4 {"ab", "ab", "cd" },
#5 {"ab", "abb", "cdd" },
```

Ranges matching your constraints are: {1.2} and {4,5}.

With `std::map<>` you have to find range for every key0, then within given key0 - do lower/upper_bound for key1, Then do the same for key2. But to do so - redefine your map from:

```
std::map<ExampleKey, T>
```

to

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, T> > >:
```

And to find all matching ranges do:

```
for (auto it0 = theMap.begin(); it0 != theMap.end(); ++it0)
{
    auto it1lower = it0->second.lower_bound("ab");
    auto it1upper = it0->second.upper_bound("ac");
    for (auto it1 = it1lower; it1 != it1upper; ++it)
    {
       auto it2lower = it1->second.lower_bound("cd");
       auto it2upper = it1->second.upper_bound("ce");
       // and now we have on of matching ranges:
    }
}
```